# Why is async considered better performing than multithreading?

Tags: multithreading, performance, asynchronous

I understand both asynchronous and multithreaded programming and I have done both and can do them with ease. However one thing still bugs me: why is the general consensus that async is better performing than multithreading? (**added:** I'm talking about the case where either approach is viable and you get to make a choice)

At the first glance the reason seems clear - less threads, less work for the OS scheduler, less memory wasted for stack space. But... I don't feel like these arguments hold water. Let's look at them individually:

1. Less work for the OS scheduler. True, but does it mean less work in total? There are still N tasks running in parallel, SOMEBODY has to switch between them. Seems to me like we've simply taken the work from the OS kernel and started doing it in our own userland code. But the amount of work that needs to be done hasn't changed because of it. Where then does the efficiency come from?
2. Less memory wasted for stack space. Or is it?

   - First of all, I don't know about other OS'es, but at least in Windows the stack space for a thread isn't committed all at once. There are virtual memory addresses reserved, but actual memory is committed only when it's needed.
   - And even if it was committed, it wouldn't matter much, because just allocating memory doesn't slow your program down. Not unless you run out of it, and modern computers have enough memory for thousands of stacks, especially servers.
   - And even if the stacks DO get committed and DO end up causing a memory shortage, most stacks will only be used a bit at the start (if your program is flirting with a stack overflow, you've got bigger problems to worry about). Which means that it will be possible to page most of them out anyway.
   - The real problem with large memory usage is that the CPU cache gets trashed a lot. When you've got lots of data all over the place that you need, and the CPU cache cannot keep up with it all and needs to fetch things from main RAM again and again - that's when things get slow. But async programming doesn't help in this in any way. If anything, it actively uses more memory. Instead of a lean stack frame we now have separate `Task` objects allocated on the heap essentially for every stack frame which contain state and local variables and callback references and everything. Plus it's fragmented all over the address space which gives even more headaches to the CPU cache, because pre-fetching will be useless.

So... which elephant in the room have I missed?

Comment: fashion. These fads for "oooh, shiny and new" come all the time, and then go just as quickly. One of my favourite quotes is "nothing sensible ever goes out of fashion" - meaning the right way of doing things will always be the right way, regardless of what everyone thinks is "better" this week.

Comment: @gbjbaanb - That could be it, but I'm not so sure. A lot of really smart guys are saying that this is better, so perhaps there's something more to it. I'd like to give them the benefit of doubt at least.

Comment: Async operation and multithreading are orthogonal concept, even if the former can usa the latter in many implementations.

Comment: @Luca - Yes, but in many cases you could solve your problems either way. For example, the typical case today is the parallel processing of incoming HTTP requests. And it seems to me that writing multithreaded code would actually be **easier** in this case. There aren't many shared resources there and synchronization is rarely necessary, so with the "1 thread per request" approach you can almost always write that code in the synchronous mindset, which is a lot easier than the asynchronous one.

Comment: define "async"?

Comment: One reason could be that threads used to be much more expensive than today. While searching for an article I once read about this (thread per connection vs async), I came across [this interesting read](http://highscalability.com/blog/2013/5/13/the-secret-to-10-million-concurrent-connections-the-kernel-i.html).

Comment: _Is_ the overall consensus that async is better performing?  async/await (at least in C# land) is _easier to write_ than multithreading (so you get better "programmer" performance), because it takes away most of the pain points, but is it better performing?  I don't know...

Comment: @DavidHaim - I'm talking about the `async`/`await` concept that is becoming ever more popular in various programming languages these days. C#, ecmascript (javascript), typescript, probably others that I don't follow.

Comment: @JamesThorpe - Well, I don't have any specific links to give you, but as much as I've seen this talked about, this is the direction in which everyone has been leaning. As for writing code - perhaps, but I'd need to ponder about that a bit. The only paint point I see about multithreading is the need for synchronization, but async doesn't take that away as such - it only does that when you "emulate" multithreading with async on a single thread. Although that might be the typical scenario for desktop applications, so you might have a point there.

Comment: sorry, it's not clear what you are asking about. is it about "task per thread vs. thread pool" or "async/await vs. how we did it before async/await"?

Comment: Honestly, `async/await` are introduced because they *were* sync programming languages and some cases just need to have promises/await to execute correct. One reason for multithreading / sync code is because of HDD searches or API calls, wich means sync code would perform better. Async isn't preventing the code from running multithreaded, just that one function (atliest in EcmaScript).

Comment: This is a good example of how fine the line is between 'opinion-based' or not. It has a [post on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347744/why-was-this-reopen-audit-question-not-considered-primarily-opinion-based)  because it was used as an audit question on the reopen queue as an example of 'properly open', which is interesting considering it has now been closed.

Comment: @KellyS.French - I read the meta post, then read it again, and I still don't understand it. What _IS_ that "audit" thing? :D Anyways, I can see why it was marked as "too broad" and I'm not upset about it. Much valuable discussion was done anyway for which I'm satisfied.

Comment: This is a very valid, valuable and educated question, stating facts and looking for facts. It's a shame that the community has decided to close it.

Comment: The question might be focused on a particular language, as each lang implements async/threads differently, which determines performance. Here's some benchmark for Python: https://testdriven.io/blog/concurrency-parallelism-asyncio/

Answer (score 17):

> why is the general consensus that async is better performing than multithreading? (added: I'm talking about the case where either approach is viable and you get to make a choice)

On the server side, `async` lets you make maximum use of threads. Why have one thread handle a single connection when it can handle hundreds? On the server side, it's not an "async vs threads" scenario - it's an "async *and* threads" scenario.

On the client side - where either approach is truly viable - it doesn't matter as much. So what if you spin up an extra unnecessary thread? It's just not that big of a deal, even for mobile apps these days. While technically, `async` can help be more efficient especially in a memory- and battery-constrained device, at this point in history it's not that terribly important. However, even on the client side, `async` has a tremendous benefit in that it allows you to write serial code rather than mucking around with callbacks.

> There are still N tasks running in parallel, SOMEBODY has to switch between them.

No. I/O tasks as used by `async` do not "run" anywhere, and do not need to be "switched" to. On Windows, I/O tasks use IOCPs underneath, and I/O tasks do not "run" - they only "complete", which happens as the result of a system interrupt. More info in my blog post ["There Is No Thread"](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html).

> Where then does the efficiency come from?

The word "efficiency" is tricky. For example, an asynchronous HTTP server handler will actually respond *more slowly* than a synchronous handler. There's overhead to setting up the whole async thing with callbacks, etc. However, that slowdown AFAICT is unmeasurably small, and asynchronous code allows that server to handle more *simultaneous* requests than a synchronous server ever could (in real-world tests, we're talking 10x as a conservative estimate). Furthermore, asynchronous code is not limited by the thread injection rate of the thread pool, so asynchronous server code responds *faster* to sudden *changes* in load, reducing the number of request timeouts as compared to a synchronous server in the same scenario. Again, this is due to "async *and* threads", not "async instead of threads".

A few years ago, Node.js was heralded as an incredibly efficient server - based on real-world measurements. At the time, most ASP.NET apps were synchronous (writing asynchronous apps was quite hard before `async`, and companies knew it was cheaper to just pay for more server hardware). Node.js, in fact, only has **one** server thread that ever runs your app. It was 100% asynchronous, and that's where it got its scalability benefits from. ASP.NET took note of this, and ASP.NET Core (among other changes) made its entire stack asynchronous.

Comment: Although it's strictly true that for sudden changes in load spawning threads would be slower, for most real-world cases that delay would be negligible. Two decades ago spawning a thread used to be a much heavier operation than it is now. With common server hardware and not-an-ancient Linux kernel, you can easily spawn 5,000 threads in about 0.1 sec. What would usually matter a lot more is _what_ those threads are going to be doing while they're running.

Comment: @at54321: The slowness in sudden scaling doesn't come from spawning threads; it comes from the (deliberately limited) thread pool injection rate. On .NET at least - not sure about other runtimes.

Answer (score 5):

(In this answer, I will talk about .NET, as it is the first technology which came out with `async/await`)

We use threads to parallelize CPU-bound tasks, and we use asynchronous IO to parallelize IO-bound tasks.

**CPU - wise:**
We all know that a thread per task is wrong. we don't want too many threads, because the context switches will freeze the entire system. we don't want too few of them, because we want the tasks to be finished as soon as possible. of-course, we're looking at some sort of a threadpool.
ThreadPool was the default way of scheduling an asynchronous task on the pre `Task` epoch. but the threadpool had one sore problem - it was really hard to know when the asynchronous is finished, and what is the asynchronous result or exception are.
Then, came the `Task`. not only does the task schedules a delegate on the thread pool, when the task is done, you can get the result or exception and continue working from them with `Task.ContinueWith`.

**IO - wise:** 
We all know that thread-per connection is a bad thing. if we want our optimized server to serve millions of requests per seconds, we can't just spawn a new thread for each new connection. our system will suffocate on context switching. So we use asynchronous IO. in the pre `Task` epoch, we used `BeginRead/EndRead` and `BeginWrite/EndWrite`, which were error prone and just pain to work with - we had to work with terrible paradigm of event-driven programing
Then, came the `Task`. we can initiate an asynchronous IO action, and receive the result or exception with `Task.ContinueWith`. it made asynchronous IO much easier to work with.

`Task` is the glue which bridges Asynchronous CPU tasks with asynchronous IO tasks. with one interface, we can schedule an asynchronous function and get the result with `Task.ContinueWith`. No wonder programing with `Task`s become so popular.

**`Task.ContinueWith` is highly unreadable and unwritable.**
basically, chaining a task to a task to a task a to task... is a headache. as Node.js developers complains (even in JS `async/await` will be standarized sometime in the future). async/await come to the rescue here. basically, the C# compiler does a neat voodo behind the scenes. in a nutshell, it takes everything that comes after `await` and package it with state-machine which is called when the everything before `await` is done. the compiler takes synchronous code (annotated with `async`/`await`) and does the `ContinueWith` for you.

So, why use `async`/`await` + `Task` instead of a multi-threaded code?

1. `async`/`await` is thre easiest way of getting the asynchronous result or exception. (and believe me, I wrote asynchronous code in C++, C#, Java and Javascript, `async`/`await` is a paradise in that field.)
2. `async`/`await` works both with CPU-bound tasks and IO-bound tasks. same interface for two different but similar fields.
3. If you want asynchronous IO, threads will not help you anyway.
4. `Task` anyway **is** a `IThreadPoolItem` and **is** scheduled to the .Net thread pool. `async`/`await` just removes the chaining hell away. back to step one -> multi thread code.
5. Tasks + `async`/`await` synchronizes the code flow for you. most developers are not system developers. they do not know the hidden costs of synchronization objects and techniques. in most cases, the implementation provided by the framework is faster than the average implementation that the average developer can think about. ofcourse if you really try, you can write something extremely customized for your needs hence more performant, but that doesn't apply for most developers.
6. Depending on you programing language, `await` can be faster than a callback. Gor Nishanov is the original (Microsoft) developer who offered standarize `await` in C++. [In his 2015 lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_fu0gx-xseY), he shows that the C++ version of `await` is actually more performant than callback-style asynchronous networking IO. (switch to 39:30)

For specific questions :

> Less work for the OS scheduler. True

**False**. `async`/`await` compiles to state machine. a task continuation invokes that state machine when its done. a task run on the threadpool anyway. `async`/`await` yields the same amount of scheduling as a multi threaded code / queuing a thread pool work. **it's the simplicity you get which matters.**

> Less memory wasted for stack space. Or is it?

**False**. again, `async`/`await` compiles to a state machine. when invoked on task completion, it will use the same amount of stack memory for local varaiables. the continuation will anyway run on a thread (usually a thread-pool thread), so that argument is invalid.

> Why is async considered better performing than multithreading?

When your code CPU-bound, there will be a little difference between between Tasks + `async`/`await` and pure multi-threaded code. In IO bound code, multi threading is the **worst** throughput you can have. Tasks + `async`/`await` will blow away any IO-bound-threadpool you can write your own. threads don't scale. usually (especially on Server side) you have both. you read some data from a connection (IO), then continue processing it on the CPU (json parsing, calculations etc.) and write the result back to the connection (IO again). Tasks + `async`/`await` are faster in this case than a pure multi threaded code.

*It's the simplicity which makes `async`/`await` so appealing. writing a synchronous code which is actually asynchronous. if this is not "high level programing", what is?*

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138536/discussion-on-answer-by-david-haim-why-is-async-considered-better-performing-tha).